# Levelling a trailer with a pair of jacks

Tags: trailer, jack

I have a car transporter trailer that I have converted to a sort of caravan which can carry my stock to trade fairs and shows. When the stock is out we sleep in it. It has drop down legs at the back but nothing except the jockey wheel at the front and I have no way of levelling it. It’s usually parked in a field which means the ground is never level. If I lower the front too much it drops off the jockey wheel (annoying to say the least!). I am looking at buying some jacks to hold up the corners and make it level inside. All these forum things say you can’t hold a car up with a jack and should use stands. My question is, can I use them to level the trailer safely for max a week or will they drop down? No one is ever going to be underneath, it’s purely so I don’t fall out of bed and the water drains from the sink! If I can do it, what sort of jacks should I buy? I am leaning towards bottle jacks because they look smaller, and easier for me to use. Thank you.

Comment: You need 4 so that each corner height can be adjusted independently. A friend who trailers a lot , carries several wood blocks so there is not so much jacking and you can get larger "footprint" on soft soil.

Comment: Caravans have screw jacks at each corner for this very purpose. Easiest to have them fitted permanently at each corner and use the blocks as well as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I have not been able to find caravan levellers that I can afford and are tall enough for the trailer so wood blocks would be a good plan if I can find some cheap corner steadies (failed so far). If I continue with the jack idea, maybe I do need 4 - I was hoping I could use 2 to level the back, put the legs down and move them to the front - I’m really trying to save money!